VS Code, adding a source file to a C language project causes an error
I am using the Raspberry Pi Pico Extension in VS Code, running on a Pi4. I am playing with the examples provided in the RaspberryPi/pico-examples repository on GitHub... for example the hello_uart example.
If I add a file to the workspace folder and name it blahblah.c, I immediately get a message saying:

"blahblah.c" not found in "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json". 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'hello_uart' will be used for this file instead.

The way I have found to get rid of this error is to add a blahblah.h file, #include it in the hello_uart.c file, then close and re-open the VS Code window.
I assume there is some more 'regular' way to tell VS Code that I am adding a source file, but I have not been able to find out how.  References to appropriate documentation will be appreciated.

When searching on Github, I do see several examples.json files, but I do not see an "hello_uart example".  Can you clear that up in your question?
